# Twig, pass in block (e.g. h1) in includes

Tags: php, html, twig, timber

If I'm including a template like this:

```
{% include 'mytemplate.twig' %}
```

Can I pass a block in like this for example:

```
{% include 'mytemplate.twig' 
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
%}
```

And have it rendered **inside** my other template.. Something like this:

```
// mytemplate.twig

<div>
    {{ content }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Pass the content as a variable :

   `{% include 'mytemplate.twig' with {'content': 'Title', } %}`

*do note you will need to modify the template to : `{{ content | raw }}` in order to parse the HTML*

2. Define a block inside the template :

   `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`

And then use `embed` instead :

```
{% embed "mytemplate.twig" %}
{% block content %}
   <h1>Title</h1>
{% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
{% include 'mytemplate.twig' 
   with {
       content: '<h1>Hello World</h1>'
   }
%}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a parent template and have `mytemplate.twig` extend it:

```
// parent_template.twig

<div>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>

// mytemplate.twig

{% extends 'parent_template.twig' %}

{% block content %}<h1>Hello World</h1>{% endblock %}
```

or pass a parameter in `include`:

```
{% include 'mytemplate.twig' with { 'content': 'Hello World' } %}
```

and in mytemplate.twig:

```
<div>
    <h1>{{ content }}</h1>
</div>
```